# Give priority to one of two element using the property 'position' in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and I got to a part where I am facing a problem.
Normally on a normal screen, my work looks like this when I hover the avatar beside the searchbar:

[image: On a normal screen]

The problem happens when I am using a small screen, the 'dropdown menu' which contains the 'my account', 'my wishlist' and 'logout' buttons does not appear when I click on or over the avatar:

[image: On a small screen]

The HTML/CSS code is the looks this (It has been reduced to detect mistake I have made easily):

```css
/*Avatar - Dropdown menu*/
.header-user-menu {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3a3c3e;
  width: 75px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.header-user-menu:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
.header-user-menu ul {
  display: none;
  font: bold 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: inherit;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 125px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header-user-menu:active ul,
.header-user-menu:hover ul,
.header-user-menu.show ul {
  display: block;
}
.header-user-menu img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  max-width: 28px;
  right: 10px;
}
/*Search Bar*/
.container-1 {
  width: 250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.container-1 input#search {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #3a3c3e;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  color: #63717f;
  padding-left: 45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-first-bar">
  <div class="header-limiter">
    <div class="header-user-menu">
      <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="User Image" />
      <ul>
        <li><a href="account.php">My account</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">My wishlist</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="logout.php" class="highlight">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help me find what is wrong with my code. Thanks

Comment: Touching the avatar in the snippet code displays the drop down on my iPhone, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `z-index` of the `.container-1` and `.header-user-menu` elements. `z-index` applies to positioned elements and specifies where the elements are in the z-axis.

> For a positioned box, the 'z-index' property specifies:
>
> - The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> - Whether the box establishes a stacking context.

*Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index*

`z-index` is in effect because `.container-1` and `.header-user-menu` have `position` set to `relative`. Because `.container-1` appears after `.header-user-menu` in the markup it's `z-index` is higher.

To fix you can remove `position: relative;` from `.container-1` as it does not appear to be needed.

```css
/*Avatar - Dropdown menu*/
.header-user-menu {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3a3c3e;
  width: 75px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.header-user-menu:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
.header-user-menu ul {
  display: none;
  font: bold 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: inherit;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 125px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header-user-menu:active ul,
.header-user-menu:hover ul,
.header-user-menu.show ul {
  display: block;
}
.header-user-menu img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  max-width: 28px;
  right: 10px;
}
/*Search Bar*/
.container-1 {
  width: 250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.container-1 input#search {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #3a3c3e;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  float: left;
  color: #63717f;
  padding-left: 45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-first-bar">
  <div class="header-limiter">
    <div class="header-user-menu">
      <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="User Image" />
      <ul>
        <li><a href="account.php">My account</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">My wishlist</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="logout.php" class="highlight">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1">
      <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its appearing but it is back side of search bar. Add `z-index` to `.header-user-menu ul`

like

```
.header-user-menu ul{
  z-index:999;
}
```

here i got this result on your snippet

[image]